# Select data from specified table names?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have searched for an answer to this however not sure if I have been looking for the correct terms?

I hope somebody can help?

I have a query that looks like this

```
select name 
from CDSArchive.sys.tables
where name like '%OPARDENTIA%'
  and create_date >= '01 apr 2016'
ORDER BY create_date DESC
```

this gives me a list of all tables in the database. These tables contain the exact same columns/data however a new table is produced every month which pulls in the most recent data.

Would it be possible to write something that automatically unions all of these tables whenever it is run? For example, I would want to run it at the end of this month and it would produce an output which is all of the tables unioned including the latest table which was produced this morning?

I hope someone can help?

Many thanks :)

Comment: You would do this by setting up a job or DDL trigger that redefines a view that combines the tables.  However, it makes more sense to modify the job that actually creates the tables to also put the data into a single table with a column for the run month.

Comment: I agree with modifying the job however they come from a different department so we have no control on the way we receive them. What would my code look like that would redefine the view? I would be able to create a view that has all the tables unioned if I enter the table name manually but I want it to automatically union them. So when a new table is added, it automatically gets included in the union without me specifying it?

Answer (score 0):

You could generate the SQL dynamically using a cursor (which will not be really bad performance-wise, since it will only iterate through as many tables as you have - one per month, 12 per year - not that painful) and then execute that dynamic query.

```
declare @tableName varchar(100),  @sql nvarchar(max) = '', @sqlInsert nvarchar(max) = ''

declare sqlcursor cursor for
select name 
from sys.tables
where name like '%OPARDENTIA%' and create_date >= '01 apr 2016'
order by create_date desc
open sqlcursor
fetch next from sqlcursor into @tableName
while @@fetch_status = 0
begin

     if @sql != '' set @sql += ' union all '
     set @sql += ' select * from ' + @tableName  

fetch next from sqlcursor into @tableName
end
select @sql 
close sqlcursor
deallocate sqlcursor

set @sqlInsert = 'insert into YourNewTable select * from ( ' + @sql + ') as t'
select @sqlInsert
```

Note: Instead of `SELECT *` I would go for explicitly selecting the names of the columns when concatenating the `@sql` string for `UNION`.

Comment: Thank you so much for this rigerta.  Quick question - if I want to put the output of this into another table where would I put my code? I have tried an insert query in the dynamic sql however it doesn't seem to work?

Comment: I edited the answer, adding a new variable called @sqlInsert which will be dynamically created when the cursor has finished and it will store the INSERT INTO query. You can then execute the last one, but you will need to provide the name of your table. You can parametrize the table name as well.